# How to get an Dictionary from Firebase Firestore in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I wonder how to get an Dictionary from my Firestore. For normal Arrays I've done it like that:

```
func returnArray(){
    
    let newpath = Firestore.firestore().collection(path)
    
    newpath.addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            
            return
        }
        
        self.Array = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> String in
            
            let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
            
            let Name = data["myField"] as? String ?? ""

            return Name
            
        }
        
    }

    
}
```

That works perfectly fine. My question is now how I have to change my code that its getting an Array out of the Firebase. I had an idea, but it doesn't work:

```
func returnDictionary(){
    
    let newpath = Firestore.firestore().collection(path)
    
    newpath.addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            
            return
        }
        
        self.Dictionary = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) ->  // I don't know what to fill here
            in
            
            let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
            
            let Name = data["AnzeigeName"] as? String ?? ""
            let ID = data["selfID"] as? String ?? ""

            return ID: Name
            
        }
        
    }

    
}
```

What can I try next?

Comment: So, you want to return a dictionary with a single key/value? In this case, do this: `return [id: name]` (Swift convention is to use cameCase for variables and CapitalCase for types, so I changed the variable names). The return type is `[String: String]`, but you don't need to specify it as it would be inferred.

Comment: Could you please tell me exactly what I have to write?

Comment: Why do you want to use a dictionary? Storing firebase data in a Class or Struct is going to provide a lot more flexibility. They have built in functionality for doing that; reading Firebase and storing it straight into your object. See [Custom Objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.map` is going to give you an array, but you can use Dictionary's `init(uniqueKeysWithValues:)` to turn this into a `Dictionary`:

```
let dictionary : Dictionary<String,String> = .init(uniqueKeysWithValues: documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> (String,String)? in
  let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
  if let name = data["AnzeigeName"] as? String, let id = data["selfID"] as? String {
    return (id, name)
  }
  return nil
})
```

It's important to know that `uniqueKeysWithValues` will crash if the keys are not in fact unique, so you'd want to check for that first (look at @New Dev's comment about `init(_:uniquingKeysWith:)` to handle this). I'm also using `compactMap` to get rid of `nil` values.

*(Note: In Swift, generally variable names are lowercased and type names are uppercased. Going against that pattern can make your code challenging to read for others)*

Comment: You can use [`init(_:uniquingKeysWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/3127161-init) to explicitly handle non-unique instances.

Comment: Jes, I think thats almost the solution, but how can I return this dictionary?

Comment: `addSnapshotListener` is an *asynchronous* function, so you won't be returning directly from it. Do you know how to setup a callback function (also called a completion handler)?

Comment: No, thanks. Im a little sad now, because I wanted to setup this dictionary-getter, so i can have an id for each element i use in my app... I`ve written before an get-id-of-this-element-function, that was asynchronous too. And when I heared, I have to set up a callback function, I tried this way, with an dictionary instead of an array...

Comment: Dictionary vs. Array won't affect the asynchronous function aspect. You *can* do what you did in your first example and just set `self.dictionary` -- just make sure that `dictionary` is of type `[String:String]` and it'll work. But, don't expect it to happen synchronously. If you need to respond to it getting set, use `didSet` on `self.dictionary` or use a callback function.

Comment: wait, if i give my function an @Binding- Variable, would it work without an completion handler or?

Comment: That depends what you're trying to do. You'd need to include the relevant code. You could definitely give it a binding to a dictionary and then respond to that in your view, for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231228/discussion-between-boothosh81-and-jnpdx).

Answer (score 0):

Firestore Example

```
{
  name: "Anonymous"
  pet { 
      name: "Max"
      age: "3"
  }
}
```

Query

```
Firebase.firestore().collection(path).getDocuments { querySnapshot, error in 
    if let error = error {
         print(error.localizedDescription)
    } else {
         for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
               let data = document.data()
               let name = data["name"]
               let pet = data["pet"] as! Dictionary<String, String>
               print("Name: \(name)")
               print("Pet-name: \(pet["name"]!)")
               print("Pet-age: \(pet["age"]!)")
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, but I need to make a dictionary out of different documents in a folder, not only outta different fields in a document.